# How can give installation permission to domain user?

Tags: windows, domain, users

How can I give installation permission to a particular domain user on a domain client machine?

Thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want a domain user to be able to install software on one particular machine? If so all you need to do is add that domain user to the administrators group on the specific machine. If I've misunderstood your question please come back.

Comment: Depending on the software the Power Users group may be adequate.

Comment: Good point, well made :)